# importing SVN Repo Maven project in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, svn, pom.xml

I have a SVN Repository who has structure like this: ABC Repo and this ABC Repo has different sub folders for example AAA, BBB, CCC etc. Pl note that there is no pom.xml in ABC folder. Now, I am interested in the folder CCC which has the structure like: CCC - branches, tags, trunk - and the trunk has src, config and pom files.

My goal is to get the Module CCC in Eclipse built and running. Therefore I have done following:
1) I have checked out the main ABC Repository in some directory.
2) Then I tried to import the project as Existing Maven Project in my eclipse.

There I selected main ABC folder in order to have all dependencies even though I am interested in the Module CCC. but in CCC (and also in some other modules) pom. xml is having error in **parent** tag. The parent tag looks like below:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.bbb.t-and-r</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>4</version>
</parent>
```

and it says:

```
Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find  com.bbb.t-and-r:parent:pom:4 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM**`**
```

How to resolve this parent tag in pom.xml problem ?

As, I am interested to build only one particular Module CCC, I have created the local maven Repository CCC and am trying to build the module : The pom.xml in CCC folder looks like below: **CCC/pom.xml**

```
project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <relativePath>../v-parent</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.b.t.test</groupId>
  <artifactId>p_test</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>ptesting</name>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
        <artifactId>v-ppp</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

To point to the pom.xml of v-parent, I have created v-parent directory in CCC directory which contains pom.xml (**CCC/v-parent/pom.xml)** looks like below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.b.t-and-r</groupId>
        <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
        <version>7</version>
        <relativePath>../parent-team</relativePath>
    </parent>

    <scm>
        <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://lpintrae.muc:4756/svn/vrve/VdZ/vdz-parent/trunk/</developerConnection>
    </scm>

    <groupId>com.b.t</groupId>
    <artifactId>v-parent</artifactId>
    <version>3.9.0</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>V-Parent</name>
    <description>Parent POM for application V</description>
```

Now as CCC/v-parent/pom.xml above refers to parent artifact in , I am not sure where should I put this parent pom.xml file. However I have put it in **CCC/v-parent/parent-team/pom.xml** for now and initial part of it looks like below.

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>   
  <groupId>com.b.t-and-r</groupId>
  <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
  <version>7</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>Parent</name>
  <description>Parent POM for all t and r projects</description>
```

Thus there are three hierarchy. original pom.xml refers to parent v-parent (artifact ID) and this v-parent refers to parent (artifact ID). My confusion is where to put these parent files and refer them in corresponding pom.xml.

With my current structure, it is giving me error (mvn package) that the base pom.xml can not find v-parent pom.xml (the first parent pom.xml)

Comment: Find the sources for the parent and run `mvn clean install`.  This will make it available locally.

Comment: The parent tag refers to another maven project that contains a pom.xml you need.  You cannot circumvent it easily - you need to find it and make it available to maven.  Given you obfuscated the information nobody can help you do that.